# How to ensure a rails f.check_box (not check_box_tag) is initially checked based on active record object attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having a heck of a time with this; I'm convinced I'm just not getting something completely obvious as I can't imagine this being this difficult intentionally. Everything else works in my form, but upon initial display, the check boxes are not checked when they should be. Here's the relevant erb:

```
<%= form_for :project, :url=>{:controller=>'projects', :action=>'update_permissions', :id=>@project.id} do |f| %>
<fieldset>
  <% @project.contributors.each do |contributor| %>
  <%= f.fields_for "contributors[#{contributor.id}]" do |c| %>
  <ul id="PermissionsList" class="permissions-grid in-line clearfix full">
  <li>

   <ul class = "clearfix permission-row">
    <li class="first">
     <%= c.check_box :is_active %><label for="<%= contributor.id %>"><%= contributor.user.whole_name %></label>

    </li>
    <% @roles.each do |role| %>
     <li><%= c.radio_button :role_id, role.id, :id=>"#{contributor.id}-#{role.id}" %><%= label "#{contributor.id}-#{role.id}", role.role_name %></li>
    <% end %>

   </ul>
   <% end %>
  </li>

 </ul>
 <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

I'm passing the is_checked attribute (for the current contributor) to the check_box helper. This is the proper way to do this correct? Here's what the generated markup looks like:

```
<ul class="clearfix permission-row">
    <li class="first">
     <input type="hidden" value="0" name="project[contributors[9]][is_active]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="project[contributors[9]][is_active]" id="project_contributors_9__is_active"><label for="9">Bill Hatch</label>

    </li>
     <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="project[contributors[9]][role_id]" id="9-1" style="display: none;"><label for="9-1_Reviewer" style="display: none;">Reviewer</label></li>
     <li><input type="radio" value="2" name="project[contributors[9]][role_id]" id="9-2" style="display: none;"><label for="9-2_Tech. Reviewer" style="display: none;">Tech. reviewer</label></li>
     <li><input type="radio" value="3" name="project[contributors[9]][role_id]" id="9-3" style="display: none;"><label for="9-3_Contributor" style="display: none;">Contributor</label></li>

   </ul>
```

The value of the checkbox is 1, as it should be, so I'm a little confused as to why it's not displaying as checked. Like I said, I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious; no way can this be this hard;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this form.

First of all, why not use rails to do the iteration for you? Second of all, html ids cannot start with digit. This approach should take care of populating the values correctly, since you're using form builder and not inserting the values by hand.

```
<%= form_for @project, :url => update_permissions_project_path(@project) do |f|
  <fieldset>

  <%= f.fields_for :contributors do |c| %>
    <ul id="PermissionsList" class="permissions-grid in-line clearfix full">
      <li>
        <ul class = "clearfix permission-row">

          <li class="first">
            <%= c.check_box :is_active %>
            <%= c.label :is_active, c.object.user.whole_name %>
          </li>

          <% @roles.each do |role| %>
            <li>
              <%= c.radio_button :role_id %>
              <%= c.label :role_id, role.role_name %>
            </li>
          <% end %>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: A few points and questions: I originally tried using :contributors in the f.fields_for helper, but the page wouldn't render at all. I have removed the spurious id's, which were an artifact of previous attempts and now have almost exactly what you've got. The only differences: I'm using "contributors[#{contributor.id}]" instead of the symbol for reasons previously stated, and contributor.user.whole_name instead of c.object.user.whole_name as that resulted in NoMethod... on nil object error. Still not working. And the value attr. in the markup is still correct ("1") WTF?

Comment: And sorry for being so chatty, but I didn't realize you could possibly do what your suggesting, I mean the c.object, or to generically access attributes from the object the form. Is that correct? It would make sense if so, just never realized you could do that. It didn't work in this case, but still, good to know if you can in certain cases.

Comment: And thank you for the help; this is seriously driving me crazy otherwise

Comment: Ah, I may have forgotten the magic dust. In Project model add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contributors`, and do use fields_for the way I presented, that's the key to having values be checked properly.

Comment: If you really want to create the form manually, you will have to specify that check_box should be checked yourself, using something like the option `:checked => c.object.is_active?` but I advise going with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` approach. Just to be clear: since you are building the form by hand in your snippet, it's your responsibility to make a condition and mark check_box as checked using `:checked => true`. If you use my approach, rails will do it for you.

Comment: I revisited it once again and realized I hadn't removed the outer, manual loop from my earlier attempt. I already had accepts_nested... in my model, so after removing the original "<% @project.contributors.each do |contributor| %>" block and reverting to c.object.user.whole_name it all worked!! This is the kind of outcome I love from these posts - problem solved and I've learned a great deal in the process. Thanks so much hakunin and everybody who offered suggestions and advice. Now I need to wrap my head around the way these various builders work better, especially forms involving collections

Answer (score 2):

The check_box form helper takes more than one argument.  You need to pass in a value for "checked_value".

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Something like

```
<%= c.check_box :is_active, {}, @object.is_active %>
```

Or, you can update your "form_for" to refer to an object that has values instead of a class name.

Comment: I tried using the api form of the call, and that hadn't worked. Actually, it's listed as "check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")" but I've not found a single resource anyplace that has it working like that. I did find several references saying that the single symbol, referencing an object attribute, should work as hakunin suggests. Following your example, I modified it slightly to be c.check_box :is_active, {}, contributor.is_active but that doesn't work either. I also tried changing the form_for from :project to @project, still doesn't work.

Comment: one other question/clarification: wouldn't setting it's default checked state to be that of @object.is_active mean that it would be on for every row, no matter the value returned from that? I'm reading that to mean, if value is equivalent to value, then be checked, so it would always evaluate to true, no?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to drop to a tag helper, and cheat a little (last parameter is 'checked'):

```
<%= check_box_tag "project[contributors[#{contributor.id}]][is_active]", '1', true %>
```

Does this work?

Comment: that enables the check boxes all the time, so it does work, but what I want is for the checkbox to be checked if the value of contributor.is_active == 1. So I tried modifying your statement by replacing true with (contributor.is_active == 1) and didn't work. Is it just me, or is this really insane? lol

Comment: Apologies - I wasn't very clear in my answer. Yes, you are right to modify the statement with the value of your is_active attribute. And of course this is what Jonathan was saying in his answer (which is better). Is your 'is_active' attribute a boolean? ... because if it is, you would use it on it's own since (true == 1) evaluates to false, which would explain the result your seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how **Rails 4** determines whether `f.check_box` will be checked when initialized:

```
def checked?(value)
  case value
  when TrueClass, FalseClass 
    value == !!@checked_value
  when NilClass
    false
  when String
    value == @checked_value
  else
    if value.respond_to?(:include?)
      value.include?(@checked_value)
    else
      value.to_i == @checked_value.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

suppose check_box here is: `check_box(:post, :title)`, then
**value** is `@post.title`
**@checked_value** is the value of check_box's `checked_value` argument (by default it's `'1'`).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this but found I was overcomplicating things.  If you are using check_box simply set a default value of true or false for that field in your database. Now my checkbox defaults to checked but will reflect the actual value if set in my model instance.

```
# For new instances, the onupdate field should default to checked
check_box :onupdate

rails g migration AddDefaultToWatchers

class AddDefaultToWatchers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :watchers, :onupdate, :boolean, :default => true
  end
end
```